# How to simulate a CAD model with real-time data using python or any other scripting language?

Tags: python, automation, cad, catia, solidworks

I'm trying to apply the concept of a digital twin and would like to update my CAD model in CATIA using real-time data. 
e.g. a servo motor cad model in CATIA/solidworks would continuously be receiving data such as speed and acceleration and I would be able to see the kinematics in CATIA/solidworks like the end result of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbVXumMtH1A . I would also like to see the stress on the motor parts like the end result of this video https://youtu.be/9glRJyWWXZw

I want to do all of this using a script that sends commands to catia/solidworks, it updates the model and returns updated parameters. Since I want it to work continuously, the state of the model must be preserved between consecutive commands.

From all the information I have come across online I'm pretty sure that it is possible but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried using pycatia but the documentation only mentions very basic functionality nothing about analysis or simulations.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I've gone through these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686812/connecting-cad-model-solidworks-autocad-or-catia-with-realtime-measurements-f, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637326/arduino-cad-simulation-in-real-time, as it's similar to my problem. Tried implementing what they suggest but the answers are quite abstract for a beginner like me. I've tried opening a cad model in CATIA and creating a mesh using python it works fine till here but I can't find any help on how to run kinematics simulation with real time data using python.

Answer (score 0):

Within your kinematic CATIA Product you could add parameters that define the elements whose attributes would change. You could then use pycatia to update those parameters which in turn would update the kinematic model.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be relevant now, but [pySW](https://pypi.org/project/pySW/) helps you update a predefined CAD models by updating its equations manager.